# Transparent background looking weird after Dithering - Pillow

Tags: python

we have a Python script:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageFilter
import cv2             
import numpy as np

def remove_trans(image):
    #Replace transparency on image with white background
    image = image.convert('RGBA')
    new_image = Image.new("RGBA", image.size, "WHITE") # Create a white rgba background
    new_image.paste(image, (0, 0), image)              # Paste the image on the background. 
    new_image = new_image.convert('RGB')
    return new_image
img = Image.open('test.png')
img1 = remove_trans(img)
img1.save('NO_ALPHA_PNG.png')
print(img.mode)
img = img.convert('LA')

img = img.convert('1')

img.save('PNG_filter.png')
```

However we have a bug there. When we load a transparent png image, and then "process" the image with the script, the transparent background is very weird. We found out the reason is the dithering. but we havent found any solution so far. Anybody knows how to get the background transparent, with dithering also?

**After process**

[image: How it looks when processed]

**Original**

[image: Original File]

Comment: Can you please add the "weird" picture and explain what you don't like and explain what you are expecting? This could help to answer your question.

Comment: I added the picture, click on the blue links at the bottom. 

Goal is to get a dithered PNG Image without background

Comment: I see that you added your pictures. Thank you. So your goal is to delet the gray checked pattern?

Comment: Yes, it should have a transparent background, or at least complete white. Also when you invert the image, it should also have a white background, so it would be good if it would be transparent.